# Inserting Google Drive image into templated html using Google Apps Scripts

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, blob, drive

I am using templated html and HtmlService in Google Apps Scripts to generate pdf reports. I am trying to insert an image from my Google Drive into the html template.

The templated html looks like this:

```
<img src= <?= DriveApp.getFileById("1234567890-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz").getAs("image/jpeg");?> >
```

and the output html looks like this:

```
<img src="Blob">
```

If I remove the `.getAs()` function then the output is:

```
<img src="image name.jpg">
```

Both snippets of code only result in a hollow, square box only a few pixels wide when the html is evaluated. Is there any way that the image can be inserted into the html instead of a `Blob` or `File` objects?

Answer (score -1):

It's because the IMG tag cannot use a blob as a source, use

```
<img src= <?= DriveApp.getFileById(id).getDownloadUrl();?> >
```

Chek the documentation [getDowloadUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getdownloadurl)

Comment: Doesn't seem to have had any effect. Does seem like it should work, though.

Comment: Is you imager shared with anyone with the link?

Comment: Is it giving you anything before transforming it to PDF, in the HTML result? Share your code so we can help you out

Comment: The download link appears in the `<img src = "">` tag, which when plugged into a new browser tab shows the image. But if I try to open the link in a tab that's not using my work email, it won't show up. Perhaps because of the sharing settings the Google servers are not able to access the image? I have the sharing settings set to "Anyone at [my domain] can find and edit" (link sharing is on), which is the most open sharing setting that I can give it.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43941270/create-pdf-from-html-in-google-apps-script-and-include-images-images-not-showi — looks like the thing is about images not getting rendered when you convert an html file into pdf, workaround is to insert images encoded into base64.

Answer (score -3):

Regarding to put an image into HTML in google apps script you should:

1. Upload to google drive
2. Get the ID of the image
3. Then put in in the format below

```
img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1dPKfyZlZFZzauqA8DcaB3h6oHX7sPqs8" width="150px" height="200px" border="5"
```

`1dPKfyZlZFZzauqA8DcaB3h6oHX7sPqs8` is the ID of the picture.

Comment: This does not work.
You need to use <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/d/FILE_ID">.